# Updated my Galaxy S II and know no spell check

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

I updated the Galaxy S II with Jelly Bean and know no spell check. I have not had time to go back to the sprint store, any ideas?

Comment: First, to make sure we know what you're asking for: please [edit] your question, add some more details describing the issue, and maybe check the spelling (no pun intended, sorry). Currently it reads as if you don't know what spell-check is. Aren't you rather meaning the spell-check functionality on the device is gone ("now there's no spell check", without the "k")?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings>Language and keyboard>Samsung keypad settings>XT9 predictive text. Then go to XT9 advanced settings and check the relevant options you would like.